# Choropleth Map color scale based on row count

Tags: python, color-scheme, choropleth

I am using Python and Dash to create a web application and have created a choropleth map using ISO_ALPHA values.

Using a call back I have filtered the data which of course updates the map, which works fine. However, I want to add a colour scale but rather based on a cell value, I would like it to be based on the row count of each country. This is aimed to display how many players are in each country

Code

```
    #call back to update map
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='player_map', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='select_list', component_property='value')]
)

def display_map(list_selected):
    dff_map = df_map[df_map.band==list_selected]

    fig = px.choropleth(dff_map, locations='iso_alpha', hover_name='iso_alpha')
    fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")

    return fig
```

thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a more efficient way, but managed to find a solution (see below)  which will create a new column 'count' and add the count values based on the count of country codes.

```
def display_map(list_selected):
dff_map = df_map[df_map.band==list_selected]

# make a dict with counts
count_dict = {d:(dff_map['iso_alpha']==d).sum() for d in dff_map.iso_alpha.unique()}
# assign that dict to a column
dff_map['count'] = [count_dict[d] for d in dff_map.iso_alpha]

fig = px.choropleth(dff_map, locations='iso_alpha', hover_name='iso_alpha', color='count')
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")

return fig
```